# Security measures for Ajax Call Post data

Tags: c#, jquery, angularjs, ajax

I want to make an ajax call and want to use the POST method. But I don't want any of the users who use the firebug or similar tools to see the raw data I am sending. I would like to make it encrypted or to hide the data using some other measures.

What is the best and optimized method to make the POST data secure.

Comment: Hi Rogur, are you saying you want to hide the post data from the users that will be posting the data?

Comment: Yes,Posting the data only. I have seen some applications doing it in an encrypted way. Just want to know any others way to do same thing

Comment: This is not possible. Even when you encrypt data with javascript and decrypt serverside.

Comment: Please refer to [this link](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/54656/protecting-form-post-values-when-on-https)

"If this was not the case, encrypting your data client side would only be marginally beneficial, since a determined attacker could intercept your javascript code used for encryption while it is being sent from the server to the client, and replace it with a compromised version."

Comment: Any best solutions that can be implemented ?